# Cannot drop constraint - nonexistent constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

I am trying to drop constraints in my table like fk and pk but its raising an error.

> Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint

But when I check whether there is a constraint or not, it shows that there is a constraint, but still the drop isn't working.

```
select column_name,constraint_name from user_cons_columns where table_name='EMP';

COLUMN_NAME CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
EMPNO       PK_EMP
DEPTNO      FK_DEPTNO


alter table emp drop constraint deptno;
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint

Comment: Try `alter table emp drop constraint FK_DEPTNO` instead of `deptno`. Looks like you are calling the column name rather than the constraint name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE EMP DROP CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table emp drop constraint fk_deptno;
```

Comment: Hello Please add some verbal explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The syntax requires the table with the foreign key and the name of the constraint. After running into the same issue multiple times I try to call both to make sure I am not accidentally calling the wrong table.

alter [NameOfTable] Drop Constraint [NameOfConstraint]

Answer (score 0):

It happens When you try to drop a constraint in child table but it actually exist in parent table. that's why you are showed nonexistent constraint. a query that bring you to the desired table is like:

```
select TABLE_NAME from dba_cons_columns where CONSTRAINT_NAME='constraint_name';
```

```sh
# result
TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
table_name
```

now you disable/drop that constraint from the resulted table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
# Table altered.
```

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
# Table altered.
```